# Configuring Org-Gcal to have subheadings within Spacemacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, spacemacs

this is a bit of a complicated case, so I will try to be as brief as possible.

I would like to use sub headings (level 2+) in org-gcal within Spacemacs. However, the sync currently only allows for level 1 syncing. However, I have manually tested replacing lvl 2 headers ** and replaced with -- (start at the beginning of a line or ^). This allows org-gcal to sync the sub-headers to the notes section of Google Calendar and allows me to take quick notes while out and about. My goal would be to automate a text replacement procedure of all *.org files w/i a specified directory by using a single custom command and ...

(a) convert all ** @ beginning of lines to -- on all files w/i specified directory (b) run org-gcal-sync to sync the modified files (c) once files are synced, reverse process and convert all -- back to ** and allow for org-mode functionality of column view, etc.

Specifically, I am using the following packages... 1) https: //github.com/sineer/spacemacs-calendar-layer (implementation of org-gcal in Spacemacs) 2) http: //melpa.org/#/xah-find (for text replacement)

I have narrowed the code down to using either xah-find-replace-text or (preferably) xah-find-replace-text-regex. However, I am pretty sure I am having issues with regex, scope, and lisp commands in general. Details are below. To be clear, if the following is too complicated or there is a much easier solution, I am open to any suggestions. Thanks in advance!!!

```
(xah-find-replace-text "aaa" "bbb" "~/emacs/org/Test/." ".org\'" "y" "y" "y" "y")
```

Using the interactive mode (C-x C-e), I have tested the above and it will replace all instances of "aaa" with "bbb", but I would prefer to use something more along the lines of (xah-find-replace-text-regex "^**" "--" "~/pathToDir" "y" "y" "y") since the matches would be more specific to the start of a line. Please note that the regex version takes 7 parameters (compared to the xah-find-replace-text which takes 8).

Eventually, I would prefer to automate by placing something similar into my .init/.Spacemacs file...

```
(defun org-gcal-sync-subchildren ()
  (interactive)
  (xah-find-replace-text-regex "^\*\\*" "--"......etc.)
  (org-gcal-sync)
  (xah-find-replace-text-regex "^--" "**".......etc.))
```

For reference: Org-Gcal: 1) current issue: https: //github.com/myuhe/org-gcal.el/issues/43

xah-find: 1) regular text find: https: //github.com/xahlee/xah-find/blob/master/xah-find.el#L556 2) Regex text find and replace: https: //github.com/xahlee/xah-find/blob/master/xah-find.el#L642

Sorry for the broken links, but my reputation does not allow me to post more than two.

Comment: @XahLee  Wow, thanks so much for replying on your package!  I did not expect you to personally reply.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issues is the regex.

This should work:

```
(xah-find-replace-text-regex "^\\*\\* " "-- " "~/emacs/org/Test/." "\\.org\\'" nil t t)

(xah-find-replace-text-regex "^-- " "** " "~/emacs/org/Test/." "\\.org\\'" nil t t)
```

Test them. If works, replace the nil to t (for write file)

You need double slash in elisp string for regex.

Comment: (still learning how to reply w/o running out of time) (continued).  I admit that my regex is extremely lacking, especially when it comes to elisp.  Regarding your code, I do believe it works, but I still need to work with it  a bit more.  I did not realize that it only worked on lvl 2 headers (e.g. `"** "` , `"-- "`, etc.).  I tried removing the space altogether to see if that would allow it to work on all sub lvls, but I received an error.  I'll play with it a bit longer, but wanted to know if there was a way to suppress  the xah-find output buffer?  Thanks

Comment: @siegfried no, cannot suppress the output, unless you clone it and comment out the last line xah-find--switch-to-output.